# Reusing SpecFlow Scenarios

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow

I've started using SpecFlow and wondering it wold be possible to reuse scenarios between specs

Basically my idea is this (i might be fundamentally wrong :) )

I have one feature written to validate the navigations.

**Feature: Navigation**

```
I should be able to navigate to all the pages i'm authorized to
```

**Scenario: Navigate to Boo**

```
Given I enter proper values in Foo
When I enter Go
Then I should be taken to Boo**
```

And then I have another spec that would validate the operational side of the Boo

**Feature: Validate if Boo is working ok**

So in here i basically need to navigate to the Boo screen first. I was thinking if I can reuse the **Scenario: Navigate to Boo** scenario written in **Navigation**

Is this possible? Else, what is the best way to go around it?

/BB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Create a class which has shared steps, common to many scenarios. In your case, this class would contain the step "When I navigate to Boo". This then would be available to other features.
2. You can have to more then one step with the exact same name/text, but you can use a [ScopedStepBinding](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-Step-Bindings) to make sure the correct version of that step is called for a feature. So you could have "When I navigate to Boo" appearing in more then one feature file, but by using a step scoping, you can control which code is run for a feature file.

Comment: Thanks Jason. pretty much what i was looking for!

Comment: Nice one :) Glad I could help.

Comment: "Create a class which has shared steps" --> This is not only an option, it's mandatory. In SpecFlow, all steps are shared. The step classes are only steps containers, but they don't encapsulate them. Therefore, it's better to organize steps in classes by a common aspect (ProductSteps, CustomerSteps, PaymentSteps, etc) rather than by feature (CheckoutFeatureSteps), because the steps will be available to other features anyway. This doesn't change the validity of your answer, but I found that being aware of this detail helps a lot while using SpecFlow.

Comment: @Francesc - I know where your coming from. Yeah, your right in saying that steps are shared regardless, I didn't make that clear in my answer. What I was trying to aim for was getting the idea of placing common shared steps into separate files, which you describe.